# Mongoose query is returning 'undefined'`

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am making a mongo query using the following mongoose syntax....

```
                // Log the search
                console.log("Searching for: " + lName);

                query.where('lname', lName)
                query.exec(function(err,results){
                        //Check for an err
                        if(err){
                                // Send the err
                                res.send(err);

                                // Log the err
                                console.log(err);
                        } else { 
                                // Send the query results
                                res.send(results);

                                // Log the results
                                console.log(results);
                        }
                });
```

The query is returning this....

```
URL: /api/search/customers/?lname=Last+Name // My variable
Query contents = Last Name // My variable
ReferenceError: lname is not defined
    at /home/collin/Documents/code/webdev/loyalty-app/api.js:311:12
    at callbacks (/home/collin/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:272:11)
    at param (/home/collin/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:246:11)
    at pass (/home/collin/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:253:5)
    at Router._dispatch (/home/collin/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:4)
    at Object.handle (/home/collin/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:45:10)
    at next (/home/collin/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/http.js:204:15)
    at Object.methodOverride [as handle] (/home/collin/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/methodOverride.js:35:5)
    at next (/home/collin/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/http.js:204:15)
    at Object.bodyParser [as handle] (/home/collin/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/bodyParser.js:88:61)
```

I am running this query out of a If, else if, else statement and the query works perfect when I run it like this, and with just the first name...

```
                // Log the search       
                console.log("Searching for: " + fName + "," + lName);

                query.where('fname', fName)
                query.where('lname', lName)
                query.exec(function(err, results){
                        // Check for an error   
                        if(err){
                                //Send the err
                                res.send(err);

                                // Log the error
                                console.log(err);
                        } else{
                                // Send the results of the query
                                res.send(results);

                                // Log the results
                                console.log(results);
                        }
                })
```

Here is a sample of what the DB doc looks like...

```
 { fname: 'First Name',
   lname: 'Last Name'}
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  I can't figure out what you're asking.  When you say: `The query is returning this....`, is that on the client side?  Or are these errors on the server side?

Comment: The error is on the server side. It happens when I am making the database query for 'lname' and the error is that its undefined. But when I query the database for 'fname' and 'lname' it works fine, as well as querying for just 'fname'.

Comment: The error is on the server side. It happens web I am making the database query for 'lname' and the error is that its undefined. But when I query the database for 'fname' and 'lname' it works fine, as well as querying for just 'fname'.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define **Schema** first.

See [Documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html)

And then **set**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
, query = mongoose.model('ex', exSchema);
```

Also you have to do **chain calling**

**Try**

```
query
.where('fname', fName)
.where('lname', lName)
.exec(function(err, results) {
    // do some with results
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but I already have a schema in place and it works fine when I'm querying for both 'fname' and 'lname'. But the issue is when I am just looking to query with 'lname'. When I do a query with just 'fname' it works perfectly fine, but not with 'lname'